# Knockout table and IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js, html-table

I have a trouble with a table on a knockout.

Initially, I have a number of columns in the table, but when I reduce the size of a window, some columns are hidden using "ko if".
IE remove these columns but does not stretch the table to its full width, reacting as if these pillars were not removed.

This is checked using the last row in the table, which is stretched to the full width of the table. Initially, the number of columns is 7, and after decreasing it equals 4. If, after reduction, you set "colspan" for a line to 7, then the line will be stretched to the normal width.

Comment: How is your table designed? Could you please add an example so that it will be esaier to reprodcue your issue and help with you?https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (PS.it would be better if you've provided a screenshot of your issue)

Comment: do you remove the thead´s td´s as well ? sound like you dont